# Python(bs4) wiki page scrape

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i want to scrape out movies titles only from the wiki page pls help me out

my code:

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_films_of_2020'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
movies = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
print(movies)
```

i just want to filter out the movie title from the structure like the one from the image should only be 'lost transmissions'

[this is the structure of one movie in the HTML:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRqpd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further work with the **scraped** table.

```
table_body = movies.find('tbody') 
titles = [] 
rows = table_body.find_all('tr') 
for row in rows[1:]: # leaving the first row, seems it is a header
    title_cell = row.select("td i a") 
    titles.append(title_cell[0].contents[0]) 
print(titles)
```

Comment: can you pls explain a bit on the for loop part specifically at the indexing part i got confused there i'm new to python and mostly at html and so i was learning scraping

Comment: Sure. I assume you meant row[1:]. Simply means leave the first row and work with the rest. Fist I assume is header row of table don't have any information which you want.

Comment: (title_cell[0].contents[0])  and this ?

Comment: select returns a list, so we get first element which is <a></a> and inside that the movie title is present in contents, we get that.

Comment: first element we get by that you mean that it grabs the very first tag with info in it in this case <a></a>  ?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you are after. If you only want to scrape [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_films_of_2020) page, there is a way easier way:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_films_of_2020")
```

which will get you all the information which is contained in that page within the `<table></table` HTML-Tag.
If you scope is more to get information of from Wikipedia you also do not have to use webscraping, since there is a pretty useful [API](https://towardsdatascience.com/wikipedia-api-for-python-241cfae09f1c).
Should your goal be, to learn webscraping (please bear always the robots.txt in mind), you can look at [this](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-beautifulsoup/) tutorial which helped me a lot.